# Cannot delete document because of update conflict

Tags: curl, couchdb, http-delete

This is how I get the document and check for newer revisions:

```
curl  http://localhost/cdb/characters/e6b153975174556adc0b344e9a000a7f?revs=true

returns:
{"_id":"e6b153975174556adc0b344e9a000a7f","_rev":"1-25b25539eca3944ef8d8f20748ed4902","name":"Barack Obama","position":"US President"}
```

Then I try to delete that doc like this:

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost/cdb/characters/e6b153975174556adc0b344e9a000a7f?rev=1-25b25539eca3944ef8d8f20748ed4902

response:
{"error":"conflict","reason":"Document update conflict."}
```

Why, if there doesn't seem to be an issue with revision, is there a document conflict on delete?

Is there a problem with deleting a doc that has no other revisions?

Comment: No, CouchDB does not have a problem deleting a document when there is only one revision as in your case. This can only happen, if there is a newer revision. Which CouchDB version is this you are working with? Your http request seems to be correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, since your code looks correct as is, check that your params are in fact being sent.

Otherwise, you should check if a revision is marked as deleted:

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/kina/  \
 04ce1239166b841ae8a317897ec45b11?revs_info=true
{
  "_id":"04ce1239166b841ae8a317897ec45b11",
  "_rev":"3-bc27b6930ca514527d8954c7c43e6a09",
  "_revs_info":
  [
   {
    "rev":"3-bc27b6930ca514527d8954c7c43e6a09",
    "status":"available"
   },
   {
    "rev":"2-eec205a9d413992850a6e32678485900",
    "status":"deleted"
   },
   {
    "rev":"1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d",
    "status":"available"
   }
  ]
}
```

To get rid of the deleted versions, you have to use _purge. For example:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/kina/_purge/ \
     -H "content-type:application/json" \
     -d ’{"7341477ce373f9cc76f351e598001cdd":
           ["2-5c7fb5dfeaf6f7cea149922fa1cdaf96"]
        }’

{
  "purge_seq":1,"purged":
  {
    "7341477ce373f9cc76f351e598001cdd":
    ["2-5c7fb5dfeaf6f7cea149922fa1cdaf96"]
  }
}
```

Comment: weird, the proxy i was sending requests through wasn't appending the arguments to the end of the string. :/

Comment: ah - so that's an issue not related to couch and you did everything correctly ;-)

Comment: ya, sorry for wasting your time! :/

Comment: _purge is no longer supported in clustered CouchDb v2.0.0 :( https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/couchdb-user-archive/yDf965WCTMQ

Answer (score 11):

Deleting a doc which has other revisions is done:
`curl -X DELETE http://couchhost:5984/couchdb/docid\?rev\=rev_number`

This helped me when getting
`{"error":"conflict","reason":"Document update conflict."}`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, but, to some people like me that were coding too late and thought the query parameter was named `_rev` instead of `rev`, just remove that underscore.

(I actually had to go as far as to enable couchdb debug logging to compare the http request received by couchdb when sent from fauxton vs. my app)